# How to delete related models of a relation in Gorm?

Tags: sql, go, go-gorm

So basically I have 3 models: `User`, `Profile`, and `Post`.

They are related like so: `User` **has one** `Profile`. `Profile` **has many** `Post`

They look like this:

```
type User struct {
    Base             // holds this object's uuid, createdAt, updatedAt
    Role     string  `json:"role"`
    Username string  `json:"username" gorm:"unique"`
    Password string  `json:"password"`
    Profile  Profile `gorm:"constraint:OnDelete:CASCADE;"`
}

type Profile struct {
    Base          // holds this object's uuid, createdAt, updatedAt
    UserId string `json:"user_id"`
    Name   string `json:"name"`
    Bio    string `json:"bio"`
    Age    uint8  `json:"age"`
    Posts  []Post `gorm:"constraint:OnDelete:CASCADE;"`
}

type Post struct {
    Base             // holds this object's uuid, createdAt, updatedAt
    ProfileId string `json:"profile_id"`
    Caption   string `json:"caption"`
    Likes     uint32 `json:"num_likes" gorm:"default:0"`
}
```

**What I want to happen** is when I delete the user, I want the profile to be deleted and all the posts that are related to it. My only other experience with relational databases are Django where this is automatic.

**What actually happens** is when I delete the user, the profile gets deleted but the posts remain in the database.

This is how I am deleting the user:

```
...
base := models.Base{Id: id}
if err := configs.Database.Select(clause.Associations).Delete(&models.User{Base: base}).Error; err != nil {
    return c.Status(400).JSON(err.Error())
}
...
```

I've already looked at [this](https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm/issues/3653) but its not very helpful. How could I accomplish this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the issue link you posted, and other related issues, it might not be possible to use `clause.Associations` for relations nested deeper than one level. In your case, the `Profile` related to your `User` is deleted, but not the `Post`s related to the `Profile`.

One way to delete all wanted associations is to use a delete hook. Either `BeforeDelete` or `AfterDelete`, depending on your setup and how strong your relationships are. For example:

```
func (u *User) BeforeDelete(tx *gorm.DB) (err error) {
  if err := tx.Joins("profiles p ON p.id = posts.profile_id").Joins("users u ON u.id = p.user_id").Where("u.id = ?", u.Base.Id).Delete(&Post{}).Error; err != nil {
    return err
  } 
  return  tx.Joins("users u ON u.id = profiles.user_id").Where("u.id = ?", u.Base.Id).Delete(&Profile{}).Error
}
```

This way, when you execute `configs.Database.Delete(&models.User{Base: base})`, it will execute the hook first, then this query.

Another way would be to execute all the queries from the hook function separately:

```
base := models.Base{Id: id}
if err := configs.Database.Joins("profiles p ON p.id = posts.profile_id").Joins("users u ON u.id = p.user_id").Where("u.id = ?", base.Id).Delete(&Post{}).Error; err != nil {
    return c.Status(400).JSON(err.Error())
}

if err := configs.Database.Joins("users u ON u.id = profiles.user_id").Where("u.id = ?", base.Id).Delete(&Profile{}).Error; err != nil {
    return c.Status(400).JSON(err.Error())
}

if err := configs.Database.Delete(&models.User{Base: base}).Error; err != nil {
    return c.Status(400).JSON(err.Error())
}
```